# Excessive "sponsored ads" in FB Lite on one of two tablets

Tags: facebook, malware, ads

As an owner of very low end (Azpen) tablets the Facebook Lite app has been a godsend, requiring very little space and eliminating the need for separate Messenger app.

I have this app installed on a 4.2.2 tablet and a 5.1.1 tablet.  On the 4.2.2 it's awesome, what FB should be.  But on the 5.1.1 there are excessive "sponsored ads".  Every third or fourth post is one of these, always asking the user to install an app.  The number of ads coupled with the small screen makes the app almost unusable, since pretty much half of what you see are these ads.

I suspect that these ads aren't really coming from Facebook but rather from something sinister, since the "hamburger menu" at the bottom right of these ads does not work.  On a real FB ad this menu gives you the choice to say "show me less like this" or similar.  But on these ads, touching the hamburger menu just refreshes the feed.

How can I isolate what may be causing this difference in behavior, and put an end to it?

Note: both tablets are rooted.

Comment: Check your apps list, there should be apps that seems unusual

Comment: Are you really using the Facebook app or a modified version? The Android Authority posted about this [here](http://www.androidauthority.com/new-android-adware-nearly-impossible-to-remove-654197/)

Comment: I sideloaded the same .apk to both tablets, that is what is so puzzling.

Comment: What about trying a different app? Since you say that you'd need Facebook and Messenger in a single app, your best bet might be [Metal for Facebook](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nam.fbwrapper).

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman your suggestion looks good.  If you care to post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major benefit of the Android OS is that, usually, there are more than just one app to accomplish a certain task.

This is also the case with [Metal for Facebook](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nam.fbwrapper), a wrapper for the site, giving the user the possibility to avoid both the official Facebook app and FB Messenger as well, for it resembles the way the site looked when visited by a mobile device, before its company's enforcing of the Messenger app, thus allowing a lightweight, all-in-one experience.

*I'm in no way affiliated with the developer of this application.*